# R.Douglas "Banach Algebra Technique Operator Theory" - Chapter 2 issue

Tags: operator-theory, banach-algebras

Just before 2.37 Corollary (Spectral Mapping Theorem) Douglas says:

> If $\varphi (z)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ is an entire function with complex coefficients and $f$ is an element of the Banach algebra $\mathfrak B$, then we let $\varphi (f)$ denote the element $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nf^n$ of $\mathfrak B$.

I'm trying to proof that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nf^n$ has sense in $\mathfrak B$ by showing that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \|a_nf^n\|$ is convergent in $\Bbb C$, but got stucked with the fact that I can't see how $\|f^n\|$ should be bounded. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $||f^n||\le||f||^n$, by part of the definition of "Banach algebra".

Comment: Ok. And the fact of $\varphi (z)$ being an entire function gives me that $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{1/n}=0$, so there $\exists\;\; M>0$ s.t. $|a_n|^{1/n}<M$. So $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \|a_nf^n\|<\sum_{n=0}^\infty (M\|f\|)^n$, but still need to ask for $(M\|f\|)$ being a real lower than 1...

Comment: Forget that $|a_n|^{1/n}$ thing! Don't tell anyone I told you to forget it, but forget it. Say $r>||f||$. The series $\sum a_nz^n$ converges when $|z|=r$. So the terms are bounded: $ |a_n| r^n < c$. So $|a_n|\,||f||^n\le c(||f||/r)^n$.

Comment: Sorry, didn't got it at all. Why assume $r>\|f\|$ ?

Comment: Read the entire comment. Recall what we're trying to prove: $\sum|a_n|\,||f||^n<\infty$.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I see it.